# Validation and verification

Tags: php, laravel-5.5

Please can someone help me with a php code which will scan and know image before uploading to the website. example only pictures of buildings can be uploaded and not any other object please.

Comment: I see that you are new here. You should read [How to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). This will improve your chances of getting someone to help you.

Comment: God really bless you ok yeah indeed am new,

Answer (score 0):

This can't be done just by PHP you can use [Google Vision](https://cloud.google.com/vision/) to detect the content of the picture. For example, Google vision will tell you if the image contains adult content or not or it is a building or not. Check out the link. They have a demo and you can upload your photo and see what you get. They have a PHP SDK that you can use.